# How to query a dataset using vb.net and ouput to a text box

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I am just getting into VB.net so please be patient. I have a program that I would like to query my dataset with 3 variables and return the value of the ID column to a text box. The 3 columns I am searching are dia, length and material. All of these will be selected from the main form by the user and the output will be the result of the selections. If there is nothing found I will have a message box asking to make another selection. Below is the code I have but I can not get it to find a result.

```
Dim table As DataTable = Database91DataSet.Tables("Sheet1")
    Dim foundRows() As Data.DataRow
    Dim X As String

    X = "Steel, Cadmium Plated"

    Dim Y As String
    Y = "[dia] = '" & dia.Text & "' AND [length] = '" & length.Text & "'"

    foundRows = table.Select(Y)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To foundRows.GetUpperBound(0)
        Console.WriteLine(foundRows(i)(0))
    Next i
```

Comment: You create the `String` `X` and then never use it.  Your `Y` filter only contains two conditions, so it's only going to filter on two columns.  You should acquaint yourself with the `String.Format` method and/or string interpolation to make building the filter `String` easier and more readable.  As for doing something different based on whether the result array is empty of not, that's what `If...Else` statements are for.

Comment: For some reason the 3rd portion got cut off for Y. Either way I can not get the filter to work and am not sure where I have made an error. Everything I have read indicates this should work.

Comment: What does the final value of `Y` look like?  That's what actually matters, not the code to build it.

Comment: They are showing the correct information when I set breakpoints.

Comment: If the filter is correct and you're not getting any matches then there are no matches to get. If there are matches to get and you're not getting them then the filter is not correct. I didn't ask you whether the filter was correct. I asked you what it looks like. If you didn't think it was correct then you probably would have changed it already. Are you keeping the value of the filter secret from us for a reason? That said, given that a diameter and a length should both be numbers, I have to question why you have single quotes around those values. Do those columns contain text and, if so, why?